# Google Fonts Won't Work

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I'm having a rather strange issue. I'm trying to include a font from Google Fonts, "Yanone Kaffeesatz", in the head of my HTML and then use it to style my h1 and h2 elements using the font-family property. But even though I followed Google's instructions my browser still displays the standard sans-serif font. Where have I gone wrong?

Screenshot: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1NCq3ch0ClzaWfniSDKQJa9C-fX9zXH8-R-I7GnjqqbI/edit?usp=sharing

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>



 h1, h2 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to reference the https:// protocol instead of the http://. It is likely getting blocked by the browser for trying to load insecure content over the secure page loaded in your browser url.

To test for this, you can also try to refresh your site without https:// and see if it display the fonts correctly.

Since your screenshot is from within c9.io's preview URL and you're eventual production site may not be using SSL. You may want to change your link href by omitting the http: part of your protocol all together and just use
`//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700` which will automatically try to pull the resource from whatever protocol the site is currently using.

---

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was away from my computer for a bit there. But I just tried your very simple fix and I have to say I was skeptical but that one "s" solved the problem! Thanks for your help! I'm just confused as to why the code Google put out for incorporating the fonts into my html head had the protocol as "http://" instead of "https://." Is "https://" good practice or are there many browsers in which referencing the "http://" protocol would produce the identical result? (I'm using the latest version of Chrome) Also, I will make sure to remember your tip about omitting "http:".

Comment: More information about this fix from Paul Irish ( Works on Chrome Dev Tools ): [The Protocol-relative URL](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). His recent update to this talks about how omitting protocol is an anti-pattern for not specifically requesting a secure resource: "Now that SSL is encouraged for everyone and doesn’t have performance concerns, this technique is now an anti-pattern. If the asset you need is available on SSL, then always use the https:// asset.". So the preferred method would now be to just always include https:// when you know its available.